# Modelo de eventos del DOM según la especificación de W3C

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas, según tengo informado la W3C plantea un modelo para la creación de eventos. Voy a poner dos ejemplos (un simple keyup) y me gustaría saber cuál debo aprender y usar.

¿Es útil aprenderse la primera forma?¿Es realmente mejor la segunda forma?

### HTML

```
 //Primera forma

<body>
 <input type="text" id="texto" onKeyUp="javascript:dataBinding(this);">
 <br>
 <p id="textonuevo">
 </p>
</body>

//Segunda forma-Propuesta por la W3C

<body>
 <input type="text" id="texto">
 <br>
 <p id="textonuevo">
 </p>
</body>
```

### Js

```
//Primera forma

function dataBinding(elem){
 var titulo=elem.value;
 document.getElementById('textonuevo').innerHTML=titulo;
}

//Segunda forma-Propuesta por la W3C

window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar(){
 document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener
 ('keyup',nuevotitulo,false);
}

function nuevotitulo(){
 document.getElementById('textonuevo').innerHTML=
 document.getElementById('texto').value;
}
```

Comment: Hasta donde yo se las buenas prácticas siempre te recomiendan separar JS totalmente de HTML, es decir no tags de `<script>` con código JS, y no inlineJs, es decir tu primer ejemplo, que siempre todo código JS quede aislado en sus respectivos archivos JS.

Comment: Por lo que dices @Lixus, y que [puedes leer aquí con todo detalle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), si hablamos de **buenas prácticas** tu primera forma queda descartada.

Comment: Las buenas prácticas te dicen que separes la lógica de la vista. Dependiendo cómo lo hagas, la primera forma puede o no ser una buena práctica. Angular y React lo resuelven más o menos así.

Comment: @Vendetta, debes aprender ambas. Desde mi punto de vista, es preferible la segunda, ya que otorga mayor flexibilidad y permite agregar múltiples `listeners`. Lo que comentan como *"buenas practicas" separar la lógica de la vista* ya hace años dejo de tener peso; `frameworks` como `AngularJS, Ember, React, Vue, etc.` obligan a meter lógica en las vistas, por lo que... desde ciertos punto de vista, ya no aplica.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Supongo que todo conocimiento es bueno y habrá que saber cuando usar un método u otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría decir que en realidad son **3** formas de crear un evento:

```js
document.getElementById("segunda").onclick = () => alert('Hola, segunda forma');
document.getElementById("tercera").addEventListener('click', () => alert('Hola, tercera forma'));
```

```html
<p onclick="alert('Hola, primera forma');">Click en mí</p>
<p id="segunda">No, en mí</p>
<p id="tercera">Yo soy el único que lo merece</p>
```

Cada elemento HTML es un objeto (*Como lo puede ser: `{dato: 3, metodo: function() { return 3; }}`*). Una de las propiedades que tiene este objeto, se llama *`onclick`*.

Las 2 primeras formas tienen como base a esa propiedad. Y cada una asigna a esta propiedad una porción de código. Luego, cuando el elemento detecta que recibió un click (el navegador le avisa), ejecuta el código que encuentra dentro de su propiedad.

La gran diferencia es que en la primera, tu código *JavaScript* se encuentra *inline* (Dentro de la línea del elemento *HTML*), mientras que en la segunda, desacopla un poco tu código *JavaScript* de HTML, permitiendo así, una mejor organización.

En casos muy simples, no es un gran problema agregar el evento de forma *inline* en el elemento HTML. Por ejemplo:

```html
<input onpaste="return false;">
```

En este caso, en tu HTML estás diciendo: *Quiero un campo de texto en mi vista y que no se pueda pegar contenido en él*. 
Es bastante corto como para ocasionar ruido en tu HTML. También bastante sencillo como para que alguien tenga dudas sobre su comportamiento. Por lo tanto, quien vea ese html, inmediatamente puede entender lo que se buscaba.

**Nota**: *Cuando agregas código JavaScript de forma inline, este pasa a formar parte del cuerpo de otra función que es la que realmente se va a ejecutar. Por eso puedes escribir simplemente `return false;`*

Ahora, cuando tu código se vuelve más complejo, ponerlo en el html empieza a ocasionar molestias. Principalmente porque no puedes diferenciar fácilmente qué forma parte de la vista de tu programa y qué forma parte de la lógica del mismo.

Un principio arquitectónico ampliamente conocido, te dice que al menos, deberías separar; 'la *vista*', 'del *comportamiento*' de tu aplicación. De forma que si quieres cambiar la apariencia/estructura de la misma, puedes hacerlo sin afectar el funcionamiento. (*Generalmente, 'afectar el funcionamiento' significa: 'bombardearlo de bugs'*).

---

```
<p onclick="function algo() { alert('hola'); } function otro() { algo(); } /*.. mucho código después ..*/ function mas() { otro(); } mas();">Click</p><p>Booh!</p><p onclick="function algo() { alert('hola'); } function otro() { algo(); } /*.. mucho código después ..*/ function mas() { otro(); } mas();">Click</p>
```

*Es probable que ni siquiera te de ganas de leerlo. E incluso, intentando leerlo, puede que se te salteen algunas cosas.*

---

Ahora, si quieres separar tu ***vista*** de tu ***lógica***, y organizar mucho mejor tu aplicación, usando la segunda forma puedes hacerlo simplemente.

Tu .html:

```
<p id="algo">Click</p>
```

El código *JavaScript* asociado:

```
document.getElementById('algo').onclick = function() { 
  alert('hola'); 
}
```

---

Ahora, **¿Qué pasa con la tercera forma?**

Como dije antes, las 2 primeras formas, asignan **UNA** función a una propiedad específica del objeto. Luego:

1. El navegador avisa al elemento que se hizo click en el.
2. El elemento ejecuta la función que tenga dedicada.

En cambio, la tercera forma, con `AddEventListener`, le dices al navegador que cuando *tal* elemento reciba un *click*, ejecute *tal* función.

**La diferencia?**

```js
let elemento = document.getElementById('click');

elemento.onclick = () => alert('uno');
elemento.onclick = () => alert('dos');

let elemento2 = document.getElementById('click2');

elemento2.addEventListener('click', () => alert('uno'));
elemento2.addEventListener('click', () => alert('dos'));
```

```html
<p id="click">Clickeame, por favor!!!</p>
<p id="click2">Yo también quiero click!</p>
```

`onclick` al ser una propiedad, simplemente le asignas un valor (*código*), por lo que cada vez que lo hagas, estás sobreescribiendo el código anterior. (*Exactamente como un `var a = 2; a = 3;`*)

Mientras que usando `addEventListener('click', funcionParametro);` solo dices al navegador que ejecute esa función, sin importar si hay o no otras. Esto te permite entonces agregar infinitos eventos del mismo tipo (*click*) a un mismo elemento. (*Bueno, no infinito, sino lo que la memoria del cliente pueda aguantar*).

***Nota***: Ver que acá, el evento se hace más visible. 'click' es un evento, 'onclick' no. Se agregó el **on** para resaltar que era una propiedad.

---

### ¿Problemas?

Asignar una función a la propiedad del objeto, fue la primera forma para dar soporte al manejo de eventos. Por lo tanto, es soportado por todos los navegadores.

Por otra parte, `addEventListener` es una solución más *moderna*. Tanto, que recién en la versión 9 de IE la soporta. (Aunque en las versiones anteriores de IE, existía un equivalente llamado `attachEvent`).

Sin embargo, hoy en día es prácticamente una función básica de *JavaScript*. Así que, salvo que tengas que dar soporte a navegadores más desactualizados (*prehistóricos*), no debería ocasionarte problema alguno.

Además, tiene algunas otras ventajas que irás descubriendo a medida que vayas requiriendo funcionalidad más específica que solamente 'ejecutá este código'.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Mas claro y completo no podía quedar. Muchísimas gracias por dedicar tiempo en responderme :)